# Is there a word for petals falling without withering?

Tags: word-request

When roses whither, the petals shrivel and dries up before falling. Is there a word like withering, but doesn't imply that the petals shrivel and dries up? Is there a word that refers to just petals falling like in the beauty in the beast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the [Glossary of botanical terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_botanical_terms), I found the term [abscission](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abscission)

> The normal separation of flowers, fruit, and leaves from plants.

which describes the process you're referring to quite accurately.

Comment: True, but that is a scientific term - it wouldn't be used in everyday conversation. We can say that the flowers fall or that the petals fall.